# ¿El cacheo http y el uso de cache en el navegador son lo mismo?

Tags: wordpress, http, cache

Quiero acelerar la velocidad de carga de mi sitio web en WordPress. Estos son términos distintos o son lo mismo? Si son distintos, Cual me recomiendan aplicar?

Comment: Hola M. Acosta, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español. Te invito a que revises este enlace: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic y modifiques tu pregunta siguiendo las recomendaciones que ahí aparecen.

Answer (score 1):

Son distintos.

Por un lado, todo navegador web tiene su propio cache; esto es especialmente útil para no bajar repetidamente recursos relativamente grandes como imágenes, librerías javascript, hojas de estilos css - y también, pero menos importante, páginas html.

Si tienes un sitio en Wordpress, normalmente, no hay mucho que hacer por este lado, aunque hay algunos [plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-headers/) que permiten hacer ajustes más finos.

Por otro lado, hay (puede haber) varios niveles de caches en el server (y también en el camino intermedio). En Wordpress, los más relevantes son los caches tipo  [WP super cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) que se encargan de guardar el código html de las páginas (dinámicas) que arma y devuelve Wordpress. Lo que se ahorra en tal caso es principalmente el tiempo de armar dinámicamente la página (lo cual normalmente involucra hacer búsquedas en la base de dato). Esto ahorra CPU y mejora la velocidad de respuesta, en el caso de consultas repetidas a las mismas páginas. Pero no influye en el volumen transferido entre servidor y browser.

Más info [aquí](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Optimization/Caching).